# Customizing search box in ember powerselect

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-power-select

I want to add a search icon inside the Ember power-select input tab. 
I don't see any method so far to customize it.
How do i do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ember Power Select is very flexible. You could pass in a custom component for nearly each of it's pieces. The search box is rendered by default by a component called [`power-select/before-options`](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select/blob/master/addon/templates/components/power-select/before-options.hbs). This is determined by [`beforeOptionsComponent`](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select/blob/master/addon/components/power-select.js#L91) property of `{{power-select}}` component. Override that property on invocation to have total control over what is rendered before the first option. Ember Power Select [provides quite a lot information](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select/blob/d30e5fdd5dd8657c723bd73fe0e042cbf8a31b43/addon/templates/components/power-select.hbs#L72-L85) to that component.

If possible I would consider styling the search box with CSS as this would be way less complex and does not add that maintenance burden.